# assign random values to excel cells from visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have tried using the random function in visual basic with string builder but it repeats the same value for each cell... I need all the cells to be different.

what im trying to say is.....

```
    Dim validchars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim rand As New Random()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 12
        Dim idx As Integer = rand.Next(0, validchars.Length)
        Dim randomChar As Char = validchars(idx)
        sb.Append(randomChar)
    Next i
    txtPass.Text = sb.ToString
    If txtPass.Text.Length > 1 Then
        Dim newvar As String
        newvar = txtPass.Text
    End If
```

I need to use this piece of code to assign values to excel cells about 1000 cells.

Comment: is the code in a button click?

Comment: I doubt that this code repeats the same value. But maybe this is in another loop which generates for example the rows, then the `Random` instance will be created too fast and it will be repeated for every row.

Comment: In response to comments above ^ yes this is a button click and it is just an example...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are outputing to Excel, just let Excel handle the random character generation.

The below would create random strings (A-Z, 10 chars long) in a 4x4 grid:

```
Dim excelRandomChar As String = "CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65, 90))"
Dim numberOfChars As Integer = 10

' Write generation formula to Excel (replace with your Excel objects).
xlObject.Sheet.Range("A1:D4").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & _
    String.Join(" & ", Enumerable.Repeat(excelRandomChar, numberOfChars).ToArray)
```

Comment: How could I do this if i was to use random characters such as ...इ増ईऊ艾अゑدㄽㅅ本はछ丝ㅁऊ ङㅊ勒غ do I just replace the 65, 90 and put ("छ丝ㅁऊ ङㅊ勒...") ?

Comment: @billyfitzgerald - I can't read the characters, but essentially you define the ASCII range you want to use for generation.

Comment: ok yeah thanks that code is working for now... but what if i wanted to say use letters "ulh" and "17GF!" how could i do this as they are not in the same range?

Comment: @billyfitzgerald - You would have to define a continuous range to pick from (http://www.asciitable.com/). Your question only utilized letters which is what I presented in the answer. If you want something more complicated then additional logic would be required.